# Can't see data on the screen but I can see it in the elements

Tags: sencha-touch

I am new to sencha touch so if someone can point me in the right direction that would be great. My problem is that I want to display data from my database. I seem to have everything working correctly when I inspect the elements I see the data but I can't see the data on the screen Here is my code:

getUserList.js

```
    Ext.regModel("User", {
            fields: [
                "id",
                "name",
                "username",
                "password",
                "email",
                "phone"
            ]
    });

    var myStore = new Ext.data.Store({
        model: 'User',
        proxy: {
            type: 'ajax',
            url : '../sencha/php/getUserList.php',
            reader: {
                type: 'json',
                root: 'results'
            }
        },
        autoLoad: true
    });



    var tpl = new Ext.XTemplate(
        '<tpl for=".">',
              '<div class="thumb-wrap" id="{id}">',
              '<div class="thumb">title="{name}"></div>',
              '<span class="x-editable">{name}</span></div>',
            '<div style="background-color:#00F" class="thumb-wrap" id="{id}">{id}</div>',
        '</tpl>',
        '<div class="x-clear"></div>'
    );

    var panel = new Ext.extend(Ext.Panel,{
        id:'images-view',
        frame:true,
        width:535,
        autoHeight:true,
        collapsible:true,
        layout:'fit',
        title:'Simple DataView',
        initComponent: function() {
            panel.superclass.initComponent.call(this);
        },

        items: new Ext.DataView({
            store: myStore,
            tpl: tpl,
            autoHeight:true,
            multiSelect: true,
            overItemCls:'x-view-over',
            itemSelector:'div.thumb-wrap',
            emptyText: 'No images to display'
        })
    });
    //panel.render(Ext.getBody());

      Ext.reg('userPanel', panel);
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

User

```
     <script type="text/javascript" src="sencha/sencha-touch.js"></script> 
     <script type="text/javascript" src="js/getUserList.js"></script> 

    <link href="sencha/resources/css/sencha-touch.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />



   <script type="text/javascript">
        var topPanel = {
            style: 'padding:15px; background-color: #F00',
            html: 'color2'
        };

        new Ext.Application({
            launch: function() {
                new Ext.Panel({
                    fullscreen: true,
                    layout: {
                        type: 'hbox',
                        align: 'stretch'
                    },
                    items:[{
                           xtype: 'userPanel'
                           }],
                    dockedItems: [topPanel]
                });
            }
        });        

</script>


</head>
<body></body>
```

Thanks for any help you can provide!

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, I had to add a layout to my xtype in my index.html file